# Trigger animation from container view

Tags: xcode, swift3, uiviewanimation, uicontainerview

Im trying to animate a UIView inside of a parent view controller from a button inside an embedded container view. I have created an action for the button inside of the containers view controller and I have created an outlet for said UIView inside of the parent view controller. If this doesn't make sense I will provide more clarity.

Comment: Add a delegate to your container to inform the parent VC the button has been pressed.

Comment: @shallowThought Haven't created a delegate before. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: Search for it and learn. If you run into   issue, update your question, show code and describe the issue in detail.

Comment: @shallowThought thank you for your 1st answer